# Calculate a different axis from given CT Images

Tags: c#, python, image-processing

I am currently writing my bachelor thesis and have a CT scan from the torso of a person.

Here is an example picture to better understand what i want to do.

[image]

I have images like the one labeled "A", but i need to write some code (the language is not that important) to get a picture like the one labeled "B". So i need to calculate a different axis.
I have arround 100 pictures that look like the one in "A". So in theory i have all the Information available to calculate the "B" type picture.
But I am a little overchallenged at this point, because i dont how to to even start this.

I have tried to google to get some examples for it but I was not able to find anything usefull..

I would love to get an idea of how to even start this or if there are any packages that can do this. This would help me alot.

Comment: Hey Chris, welcome... 
First of all I recommend you read this.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Specifically regarding your question:

So much of this is platform and technology specific to the software, hardware, sdk, api or whatever is required to capture the images. Typically, you would post code illustrating what you have tried so far (research, hardware info, tools, code example, algorithms ) before asking for someone to do this for you. 

There is a lot of information that would be needed to properly answer your question.

Comment: If this is strictly an image transformation or comparison type question then I'd recommend you start looking into tooling such as https://opencv.org/ to determine if there is a way to accomplish what you are asking.

Comment: Do a search on web for photo stitch